# Is AlarmManager suitable for writing clock widget?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, clock

I want to write my own clock widget on Android. I am using my own icons to show the time (i.e., updating the ImageView(s) every second). I found a method using AlarmManager to handle the update and implemented it, but I have noticed that the app is using up my battery quickly, which I guess is because of the frequent update.

Is there a more efficient method to do the update?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks & Regards,
Patrick

Comment: Sorry, folks. I am answering my own question now. Having searched more topics on this forum, I believe I have done all the "right things" with AlarmManager. I used the following in my code:alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC,...). It seems like I was looking into the wrong place for information. I looked at the log on the emulator, which showed that the widget never goes to sleep, which I now know is a limitation of the emulator. Anyway, I will look at other possible reasons for my battery drain. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Battery drain on a frequently updating widget can come from:
*keeping the device awake
    --do you really need to wake up the device each time - choose RTC not RTC_WAKEUP
*processing a lot of code each time the widget updates
    --do you run a lot of code in onReceive in your broadcast receiver? change your process strategy to do as little processing as possible, because updating every minute is a lot! for example, dont generate data that doesnt need to be updated.